# @EnableDiscoveryClient spring Boot service registration

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

i am running a spring boot application into docker container using eureka netflix service discovery with `@EnableDiscoveryClient` annotation.
Running my application, it registers itself into eureka with a specific ip address (that of  the docker container).
i want to change this ip to the host machine ip address, so that my application will be registered into eureka with the host ip address were my container is running.

Answer (score 1):

Check this issue. This topic has already been discussed there - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/432

Comment: but no clear answer. i did "docker run -h host_ip" but nohing changed. Eureka still register my application with container ip